# How do I retrieve the first found element with the lowest value within a vector

Tags: c++, search, vector, a-star

I've implemented A*. However, when it runs, it operates as BFS when all nodes within the vector have equal f-scores.

> There are a number of simple optimizations or implementation details that can significantly affect the performance of an A* implementation. The first detail to note is that the way the priority queue handles ties can have a significant effect on performance in some situations. If ties are broken so the queue behaves in a LIFO manner, **A* will behave like depth-first search among equal cost paths** (avoiding exploring more than one equally optimal solution)
>   [Wikipedia- A*]

I would like to know if there is a way to modify my existing program (snippet provided) to retrieve not only the lowest element but the first lowest element.

```
void Search::aStar()
{
    searchMethod = "ASTAR";
    generateMap();

    // Draw Window and wall
    guiOpen("VisX", 800, 600);
    guiShowWall();

    std::vector<Node> nodeHistory;
    std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<Node>> openSet;

    // Get starting point, add it to the queue and set as visited
    Coord start = getStartPos();
    Node &root = mapMaze[start.x][start.y];
    openSet.push_back(root);
    root.setVisitFlag(true);

    root.setGScore(0);

    while (!openSet.empty())
    {
        // Put the minimium fscore element to the front 
        auto result =  std::min_element(openSet.begin(), openSet.end(), lowestFScore());
        int minElementPos = std::distance(std::begin(openSet), result);
        std::swap(openSet[minElementPos], openSet.front());

        Node &current = openSet.front();

        // Re-assign pending flag to visited
        current.setPendingVisit(false);
        current.setVisitFlag(true);

        // Update the GUI display
        guiRefresh(current);

        openSet.erase(openSet.begin());

        // Add to list of visited nodes 
        nodeHistory.push_back(current);

        if (current.isFinish())
        {
            std::cout << "[Informed] A*: Found Finish"
                      << "\nNote: Speed of search has been slowed down by GUI display."
                      << std::endl;

            // Construct path & update GUI with path
            constructPath(nodeHistory);
            guiShowConstructedPath();

            guiClose();
            break;
        }

        // Add each valid edges node to the queue
        for (int i = 0; i < EDGE_AMOUNT; i++)
        {
            if (current.isValidEdge(i))
            {
                Node &neighbor = mapMaze[current.getEdge(i).x][current.getEdge(i).y];
                // If not a wall and has been visited, ignore
                if (neighbor.isNotWall() && !(neighbor.isNotVisited())) continue;

                // If not in openset, add it and set flag
                if (neighbor.isNotWall() && neighbor.isNotVisited() && neighbor.isNotPendingVisit())
                {
                    // Add to queue and set flag
                    openSet.push_back(neighbor);
                    neighbor.setPendingVisit(true);

                    // Update the GUI display
                    guiRefresh(neighbor);
                }

                // Calculate gScore, and see if it is better than neigbours current score.
                #define MOVEMENT_COST (1)
                int tentativeGScore = current.getGScore() + MOVEMENT_COST;
                if (tentativeGScore >= neighbor.getGScore()) continue;

                // This path is the best until now. Record it!
                neighbor.setParent(current);
                neighbor.setGScore(tentativeGScore);
                int fScore = neighbor.getGScore() + neighbor.getHScore();
                neighbor.setFScore(fScore);
            }
        }
    }
}
struct lowestFScore
{
    bool operator()(const Node& lhs, const Node& rhs) const
    {
        return lhs.getFScore() < rhs.getFScore();
    }
};
```

Comment: @Holt I've updated the question to include the full A* implementation

Comment: Your quote involves a priority queue, your code does not use one, which is probably why it is very slow. You cannot optimize something you are not using.

Comment: @Holt I tried to implement priority queue however, it does not allow for dynamic-priorities. So I used  Mark B answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2921349/priority-queue-with-dynamic-priorities.

Comment: @Holt But I would like to know how I would be able to modifiy my exisiting program to get the first lowest element.

Comment: You already have the first lowest element with `min_element` since you are adding element to the back of the vector. You simply need to use `min_element` with reverse iterators. But before looking at such optimization you should refactor your code: even without dynamic priorities, a basic priority queue with duplicate elements is likely faster than your code, why do you swap the min with the first element and then erase the first element while you could simply erase the element in its current place?

Comment: To deal with duplicates: `while (openSet.size() && openSet.front().isVisited()) { openSet.pop(); }`

Comment: @Holt and Caleth:  You are right. I need to add duplicates rather than re-ordering or making the heap. The performance implications will be less. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your `Node`s into a structure like this:

```
struct OpenNode
{
    const Node &node;
    const unsigned int order;
};
```

And define your `openSet` like:

```
std::vector<OpenNode> openSet;
```

Initialize an `unsigned int counter` to 0 before the `while` loop and make these changes:

```
// Add before while loop
unsigned int counter = 0;
// ...
Node &current = openSet.front().node;
// ...
openSet.push_back({neighbor, counter++});
```

And finally adapt `lowestScore`:

```
struct lowestFScore
{
    bool operator()(const OpenNode& lhs, const OpenNode& rhs) const
    {
        auto lScore = lhs.node.getFScore();
        auto rScore = rhs.node.getFScore();
        if (lScore == rScore)
        {
            // Bigger order goes first
            return lhs.order > rhs.order;
        }
        return lScore < rScore;
    }
};
```

As suggested, you may want to switch your `openSet` to a [`std::priority_queue`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue), which will retrieve minimal elements faster. You should be able to use the same comparison logic.

Answer (score 2):

There is a priority_queue in std.

Here is a reference: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue

I'm not sure if it is what you need:

```
#include <queue>
std::priority_queue<int, std::vector<int>, std::greater<int>> pq;
pq.push(1);
int min_elem = pq.top(); pq.pop();
```

Comment: Afaik priority queues do in fact behave like a LIFO structure in the case of ties, or maybe it is not defined, but it is definitely not like a FIFO...